# Is it possible to write division equation in more rows?

Tags: math-mode, multirow

I´m trying to write a division equation with text, and due to the length of the text, I hope to write the equation in more rows, which means, the denominator uses 2 rows("relative" and "displacement" write in 2 rows), and so is in numerator.

Is that even possible ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
\begin{gather*}
(\mbox{percentage error})_{max}=100\ *\ \frac{\abs{\mbox{ relative  displacement(t)}_{A}-\mbox{relative displacement}(t)_{B}}_{max}}{\mbox{relative displacement(t)}_{A}},
\label{eq:percentage_error}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use “pe” and “rd” for “percentage error” and “relative displacement” respectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use symbols instead of long words:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

In the following formula, $\tvar{pe}$ stands for \emph{percentage error}
and $\tvar{rd}$ for \emph{relative displacement} depending on time.
\begin{equation}
\tvar{pe}_{\mathrm{max}}=
100\,\frac{\abs{\tvar{rd}(t)_{A}-\tvar{rd}(t)_{B}}_{\mathrm{max}}}{\tvar{rd}(t)_{A}},
\label{eq:percentage_error}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative

```
\begin{equation}
(\text{percentage error})_{\mathrm{max}}=
100\,\frac{\abs*{
  \begin{multlined}
  \text{relative displacement}(t)_{A}\\
  -\text{relative displacement}(t)_{B}
  \end{multlined}
}_{\mathrm{max}}}{\text{relative displacement}(t)_{A}},
\label{eq:percentage_error}
\end{equation}
```

is not pretty.

[image]

Another possibility is `multline`:

```
\begin{multline}
(\text{percentage error})_{\mathrm{max}}\\
=100\,\frac{\abs{
  \text{relative displacement}(t)_{A}
  -\text{relative displacement}(t)_{B}
}_{\mathrm{max}}}{\text{relative displacement}(t)_{A}},
\label{eq:percentage_error}
\end{multline}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See if the following solution is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(\mbox{percentage error})_{\max}
    = 100*\frac{\left|\addstackgap{\stackunder{relative}{displacement$(t)_{A}$}} -
                      \stackunder{relative}{displacement$(t)_{B}$}\right|_{\max}}
               {\stackon{displacement$_{A}$}{relative}},
\label{eq:percentage_error}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Nicer result is obtained if instead `\stackunder` is used `\Centerstack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
(\mbox{percentage error})_{\max}
    = 100*\frac{\left|\Centerstack{relative displacement$(t)_{A}$} -
                      \Centerstack{relative displacement$(t)_{B}$}\right|_{\max}}
               {\stackon{displacement$_{A}$}{relative}},
\label{eq:percentage_error}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for info. In the first I use only `\stackon` which I later change to `stackunder` and forgot to change their content. I edit my answer.